# How can change boolean type icons to oposite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I'm want the empty key called archive has the check and with the values "true" has the line icon.

Here is the example: I want the opposite to the column status. Without change the tableIcons.js

Here is the code and codesandbox example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import SaveAltIcon from "@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt";
import tableIcons from "./TableIcons.js";

const rando = max => Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

const rawData = [
  { id: 1111111111, archive: "true", type: "CC" },
  { id: 2222222222, archive: "", type: "RR" },
  { id: 3333333333, archive: "true", type: "CC" },
  { id: 4444444444, archive: "", type: "PS" },
  { id: 5555555555, archive: "true", type: "II" }
];

const columns = [
  { title: "Id", field: "id" },
  { title: "Type", field: "type" },
  { title: "Status", field: "archive", type: "boolean" }
];

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(rawData);

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
      title="Starter Template"
      icons={tableIcons}
    />
  );
};

render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-starter-template-0s0np?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I modified the archive prop value from `"true"` to `true` in order to make conditional checks easier, this way the type is boolean instead of string.

Then I imported Check and Remove icons from the depency you were already using:

```
import { Check, Remove } from "@material-ui/icons";
```

And finally where the columns const is defined, I pass a function to the render prop, like this:

```
render: rowdata =>  rowdata.archive !== true ?  <Check /> : <Remove />
```

Ofcourse you can change the conditional if needed. Link to the Material-Table documentation on this topic [here](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/custom-column-rendering).

This is your code after the modifications:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import SaveAltIcon from "@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt";
import tableIcons from "./TableIcons.js";
import { Check, Remove } from "@material-ui/icons";

const rando = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

const rawData = [
{ id: 1111111111, archive: true, type: "CC" },
{ id: 2222222222, archive: "", type: "RR" },
{ id: 3333333333, archive: true, type: "CC" },
{ id: 4444444444, archive: "", type: "PS" },
{ id: 5555555555, archive: true, type: "II" },
];

const columns = [
{ title: "Id", field: "id" },
{ title: "Type", field: "type" },
{
    title: "Status",
    field: "archive",
    type: "boolean",
    render: (rowdata) => (rowdata.archive !== true ? <Check /> : <Remove />),
    // the ternary expression above is the same as:
    // if (rowdata.archive !== true) {
    //   return <Check />;
    // } else {
    //   return <Remove />;
    // }
},
//
];

const App = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState(rawData);

return (
    <MaterialTable
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
    title="Starter Template"
    icons={tableIcons}
    />
);
};

render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Here is the link to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-custom-column-8zwe1?file=/src/index.js:0-1276). I hope this works for you!